# request boddy is null on spring boot

Tags: java, typescript

I have a Resource with a post request with a body that mook the user members

```
 @PostMapping
    public void post(@RequestBody RestUserDTO restUserDTO) {
        try {
            registrationService.doRegistration(restUserDTO);
        } catch (BadEmailException | PasswordIsNotSecureException | BadUsernameException exception) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, exception.getMessage(), exception);
        }
    }

Rest user DTO is a internal class that looks like this 

package com.wout.webresources.register;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(name ="restUser" ,propOrder = {"firstName,lastName, userName,password, setPasswordConfirmation,email"})
public class RestUserDTO {

    @JsonProperty(value = "username")
    String username;

    @JsonProperty(value = "password")
    String password;

    @JsonProperty(value = "passwordConfirmation")
    String passwordConfirmation;

    @JsonProperty(value = "firstName")
    String firstName;

    @JsonProperty(value = "lastName")
    String lastName;

    @JsonProperty(value = "email")
    String email;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }

    public RestUserDTO() {
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPasswordConfirmation() {
        return passwordConfirmation;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirmation(String passwordConfirmation) {
        this.passwordConfirmation = passwordConfirmation;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

additionally, I have a typescript interface in order to use the same members in both places

```
  singUp(){
    const _restUser:RestUserDTO= {}
    _restUser.username="admin";
    _restUser.password="password";
    _restUser.email = "email";
    _restUser.firstName = "firstName";
    _restUser.lastName = "lastName";
    _restUser.passwordConfirmation = "passwordConfirmation"

    this._service.singUp(_restUser)
    .subscribe(data =>console.log(data));
  }
```

I make the request from post man and from browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG2Wl.png)

but somehow the object from the server have all fields null

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KilKo.png)

why this issue occurs and how can I solve this

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to add an endpoint URI to the @PostMapping. I suggest that you debug/run the Spring Boot app locally from your IDE, put a breakpoint, and send a test request via curl. This should lead you to the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Hello all in the meanwhile discovered that was caused by my Ts class and the request was something like {RestUser:{
username: username,
password: password....}}  must be very careful with the structure of the request to be exactly 1:1 and using public seters and getters
thank you